# subscribe mail isn't working in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, newsletter

I have disabled this part from newsletter.xml

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and directly using this part  in the header

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Join') ?>" class="button"><p>JOIN</p></button>
</form>
```

from the code of subscribe.phtml. But it does't subscribe email. Whats wrong or is that a SMTP problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you put the code into the template of the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` block the `getFormActionUrl` method originally referenced to `Mage_Newsletter_Block_Subscribe` is not returning a right value anymore.

So replace

```
<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true)) ?>
```